# Connect Db using SSH connection with port forward in hibernate

Tags: java, database, oracle, hibernate, ssh

I have Ssh-rsa key for ssh connection. First i want to establish SSH connection with port forward, once connection established then need to connect to DB.

Need to implement this to Hibernate. I have searched it in Google, but didn't get correct answer.

Kindly some one help me.

Regards,
Parthiban.

Comment: I think this one here might help you: http://keylesson.com/index.php/2015/06/24/connect-to-remote-database-through-ssh-2029/. UI think it describes best what you need using two methods.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Checked the link which you mentioned. Here SSH connection established by using JAVA. But i want to implement the same using Hibernate.

Comment: Check the documentation for Hibernate: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html -> There they mention only JDBC type of connection for it. I think that Hibernate only supports that and doesn't have this capability built-in. Just a question, why would you want to do this out of Hibernate and not just establish a tunnel (using the method above), then after it, just configure Hibernate's jdbc connection and it should be ok. I just don't understand the purpose of this constraint ...

Comment: Thanks. I got idea from your comment. I already have a java class to establish SSH connection. Now i need to call that java class from hibernate and provide LOCAL PORT as parameter. Is it possible to call java class from hibernate?

Comment: Well it depends on your application, but Hibernate in general is used in Java related projects (not only of course). What I can tell you is that Hibernate could be used in conjunction with the rest of your application, it really depends on your project.